# Upgrading from Textmate to a real IDE

Tags: php, ide

I've recently started using PHP for OO development.  On OSX, I have outgrown Coda and feel like Textmate takes more time to set up than to actually use.  I've downloaded a few of the "real" IDEs, but I feel like they are overkill and I can't find any way to ease myself into it and/or they are way too busy.

I'm looking for something that does code folding, validation, can colorize PHP/PDO/HTML in the same document, and hopefully do completion of my classes and methods that doesn't require 6 months to be productive again.

Can anyone throw me a bone?

Comment: you have outgrown Coda ? what do you mean ? allso witch of the "real" ides did you tryed ?

Comment: do u do alot of front end development? JavaScript etc?

Comment: Yes.  A lot of my development is now with building intranet apps that have to interface with some of my company's outdated tools. So I'm doing a little bit of everything.

Comment: After more painstaking hours wasted trying all the various apps, I settled on a hybrid of two:  PHPStorm 2 is my main IDE and Textmate is now my simple one-off tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use netbeans 6.9.1 and have been very happy with it.  Here are my favorite features:

-- functions, classes, comment blocks and other structures are automatically set up for code folding, but you can also highlight any block and make an arbitrary code fold.

-- syntax highlighting is good

-- full support for new php 5.3 features (namespaces etc.)

-- the autocomplete works, but also stays out of the way when I don't need it.

-- refactoring works really well

-- it has a lot of built in macros, plus you can create your own

-- it does nice, fast code validation.

-- completely supports xdebug through a local/remote web server.

-- has built in symfony support

-- tracks polymorphism well

-- I program a lot of c/c++ and java as well, so its really nice to get familiar with just one IDE.

-- it has seamless built in supprt for SVN/CVS and other SCMs.  Things like renaming/deleting a file in the IDE play nice with your SCM.  You can also commit, update, diff etc. in the ide.  It also does live diff via colors on the left hand side.

-- I really like the scm diff features.

-- the learning curve isn't too steep, I feel the IDE's features/commands are pretty intuitive.

Overall I have been really happy with netbeans.  I have used a lot of other IDE's and none of them are bad, but they just lack certain features that I need.  netbeans is not perfect either, but for me its the best IDE I have been able to find.  The things I don't really like about netbeans are:

-- everything has to be a project, you can't just work on some code without netbeans creating metadata.  However, the location of the metadata storage is customizable, so it doesn't interfere with your source file directory structure.

-- profiling doesn't really work unless you install some weird solaris stuff.

-- it can't mount an svn+ssh working copy, you have to pull it down locally. if you want to use the SCM features.

-- it can be a little slow if you have a lot of large projects open at a time.  You can close the projects so netbeans doesn't scan the source code continuously, and that helps.  Re-opening a project isn't too slow or difficult either.

All in all, netbeans isn't really breaking any new ground, vim, eclise, phpide and others all do similar things.  I just feel like those things work better in netbeans and are easier to access.

hth

Comment: I had done some research on NetBeans before, but only after reading your write up did I actually find any good documentation on getting started with it: http://netbeans.org/nonav/kb/trails/php.html  I'm going to check this out!

Comment: Yea, the documentation has gotten better recently.  I have used that KB tons to get my install customized perfectly for my uses.

Answer (score 3):

- [Aptana](http://aptana.com/)
- [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)
- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/projects/php/)
- [Kate](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Kate+PHP+Browser+Plugin?content=46065)

Currently I'm using Aptana Beta 3 and there are a couple of bugs, but with the new IDE coming out in a couple of months it should be great. Been a avid Aptana user for a couple of years now.

NOTE: Aptana was Acquired by Appcelerator

Comment: Komodo, Zend, Geany ... there are tons , i stil don't get it how can he outgrow Coda ? i've allways enjoied it

Comment: @poelinca - It gets very difficult whenever I can't do code folding in a large object.  I thought I could live without it, but turns out it can be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have to suggest vim despite potentially not meeting your last requirement: "doesn't require 6 months to be productive again".

Vim does everything you listed, but has a very steep learning curve. Not likely six months, but you will be fumbling around for a while. In the long run it you'll probably find it worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) on a regular basis, but have been thinking about checking out [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). It looks like it could be a nice alternative (albeit not free).

Comment: Any good links you can provide to help push me in the right direction on setup and usage?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use of Nusphere php ide , its too great for php, it has auto complete features and in built server and you can debug run time, you can also set browser for debugging your code , its true php debugger, i am using this debugger since last 3 years ,it’s amazing and it has inbuilt ftp feature so you can also debug your ftp file.